# Is there a way to create a dynamic table in excel using 3 arrays?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 arrays of texts that comes from 3 different tables. for instance {a,b}, {w, x, y} and {@, #}, and I need to dynamically create a table like:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | w | @ |
| a | w | # |
| a | x | @ |
| a | x | # |
| a | y | @ |
| a | y | # |
| b | w | @ |
| b | w | # |
| b | x | @ |
| b | x | # |
| b | y | @ |
| b | y | # |

Tried using MAP function but struggling on my own and the documentation on MS website didn't help me much. Any ideas?

Comment: It is weird that when it works wonderfully when I copy and paste the formula, but not when I change the references for the real datasources

Comment: Trying to find how to upload an image to show what is happening but I don't seem to be able to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Combine 3 Columns Using the `RepeatCol` Lambda Function

```
=LET(data1,B3:B5,data2,B7:C7,data3,B9:C11,
    RepeatCol,LAMBDA(data,repeats,IF(SEQUENCE(,repeats),data)),
    a,TOCOL(data1,1),b,TOCOL(data2,1),c,TOCOL(data3,1),
    ra,ROWS(a),rb,ROWS(b),rc,ROWS(c),
HSTACK(TOCOL(RepeatCol(a,rb*rc)),
    TOCOL(RepeatCol(TOCOL(RepeatCol(b,rc)),ra),,1),
    TOCOL(RepeatCol(c,ra*rb),,1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the 3 options. I have a lot to learn with all 3 and will spend some time on them.
This was my 1st question posted here and very humbling experience. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Try something along the lines :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _x, {"a","b"},
     _y, {"w","x","y"},
     _z, {"@","#"},
     _w, TOCOL(_x&"|"&TOCOL(TOCOL(_y)&"|"&_z)),
     SORT(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&_w,"|",{1,2,3}),"|")))
```

---

One more addition:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=TEXTSPLIT(ARRAYTOTEXT({"a ";"b "}&TOROW({"w ";"x ";"y "}&{"@","#"}))," ",", ")
```

---

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case of single characters you could use:

`=MID(TOCOL({"a";"b"}&TOROW({"w";"x";"y"}&{"@","#"})),{1,2,3},1)`

No lambda required in this case; combining a horizontal array with a vertical one creates all combinations of the 2.

If we flatten them to combine with the next transposed array, the same will happen on the combined array.

Because it would create a spill range of 1 column of a combination of the 3 characters for each cell, we can use `MID(array,sequence(,3),1)` or `{1,2,3}` to split the characters. And spill them to a range

Comment: The TOROW or TOCOL is pretty much needed even for more than 1 char. It was the only way I could get all suggested approaches to work when I plugged in the data sources I have.

Comment: for more characters you need `=LET(a,A1#,b,A4#,c,A5#,
x,TOCOL("|"&TOCOL(a)&"|"&TOROW(TOROW(b)&"|"&TOCOL(c)&"|")),
TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(x,"|",SEQUENCE(,3)),"|"))` same as Mayukh posted, but with range reference to arrays.and explicitly mentioning the TOCOL and TOROW for each array, so no matter if it's horizontal or vertical orientated, the formula will work.